# Running a subset of unit tests when source file changes using Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle

I use the gradle 3.5 build system and have several Unit and Integration tests in a Java project. When I make changes in the source files (`sourceSets`), gradle's compilation avoidance and incremental compilation makes sure only the relevant source files are compiled, which is a huge timesaver. However, *all* the tests run for every change made in the `sourceSet`. Can gradle identify and run only the relevant subset of Unit tests instead of all? If not, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Gradle can do that, but AFAIK not out of the box.

Gradle task can tell which files have been changed if the task is implemented as an [Incremental Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:implementing_an_incremental_task). The Test task in Gradle is not incremental. Fortunately it's easy to turn it into one by extending it:

```
class TestWatcher extends Test {

    @TaskAction
    void executeTests(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
        if (inputs.incremental) {
            def outputDir = this.project.sourceSets['test'].output.classesDir.absolutePath
            this.filter.includePatterns = []
            inputs.outOfDate { InputFileDetails change ->
                def candidate = change.file.absolutePath
                if (candidate.endsWith('.class')) {
                    candidate = candidate
                            .replace('.class', '')
                            .replace(outputDir, '')
                            .substring(1)
                            .replace(File.separator, '.')
                    this.filter.includePatterns += candidate
                }
            }
        }
        super.executeTests()
    }
}
```

This task is incremental (the main method takes the `IncrementalTaskInputs` as its argument). If the inputs are not incremental, it simply runs the original task. If the inputs are incremental, it iterates through the changes and sets up the `includePatterns` to include all classes. This will then run only the tests that have been changed.

You can use this task in your `build.gradle`:

```
task testWatcher(type: TestWatcher) {
}
```

It accepts all of the default test task configuration. You can place the task code directly in the script or under the `buildSrc` folder.

For more information you can see [this article](http://sm4.github.io/2017/04/25/Continous-testing-with-JUnit-and-Gradle/) I wrote. It shows how to use this with the continuous build support to re-run only the changed tests whenever the code changes. The code from the article can be found in [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sm4/gradle-example-continuous-testing), where you will find the above code as well in a self-contained example.

Comment: See also this question of mine on the forums. Might start work on this if there is no reply... https://discuss.gradle.org/t/incremental-testing-support/24785

Comment: Link for article is broken. :(

Comment: I stopped working on the blog. But you can get the article from here: https://github.com/MartinTeeVarga/sm4.github.io/blob/master/2017/04/25/Continous-testing-with-JUnit-and-Gradle/index.html 
You can download the file. It won't have any formatting, but you can also build the whole blog if you want.